# Using Eclipse with Play Framework 2.0

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

I am new to Framework 2.0.  In Play 1.0, after you Eclipsify your project, you have have a *.launch file that you can use to launch your project.

After you eclipsify in Play 2.0, you don't seem to have anything similar.  Is there a way to control your launching and to debug Play 2.0, using Eclipse?

A similar question:  [Debug Playframework 2.0 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778849/debug-playframework-2-0-in-eclipse)

The answer to that question did not have specific enough instructions for me to know how to follow.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Question 1:

After you have eclipsified, open Eclipse and choose `File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into Workspace`. A dialog will open, choose your Play Framework 2.0 project folder and click `Finish`.

Question 2:

1. Start your Play Framework application using `play debug run`. You will see something like this:

   Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
   ...
2. In Eclipse, right-click on your project in `Project Explorer` and choose `Debug As -> Debug Configurations...`.
3. A new dialog called `Debug Configurations` will open. Double-click on `Remote Java Application` and a new window will appear on the right side. Change the `Connection properties` so that the point to host `localhost` and port `9999`. Confirm by clicking the `Debug` button.
4. Put a breakpoint in your Application in Eclipse.
5. Try your application as normal in a web-browser. If it hits a breakpoint then Eclipse will be brought as frontmost and let you debug.

Comment: You can use play debug ~run to let play auto compile after a save ( when you modify source code)... Works like a charm for me

Comment: is there a way to debug tests?