# How to run a playframework-2.x project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

I use eclipse wpt 4.2

I've been trying to find how to run a Java Play2.1 project in eclipse but I can't find an easy way. Here is what I've done

Create a project

```
play new myApp
```

Go to the folder

```
cd myApp
```

Eclipsify the project

```
play eclipse
```

I've read the [How to run a Play project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784090/how-to-run-a-play-project-in-eclipse), but it is play1.x when play upgrade to 2.x everything change:

Run --> Run Configurations --> Java Applications --> myApp
with main class: javassist.tools.web.Webserver with port 9000, but fail as:

then I visit address:  127.0.0.1:9000
with my browser show:

Bad Request

Comment: Maybe you can see the answer on this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038673/using-eclipse-with-play-framework-2-0

Comment: I can not click debug Remote Java Application, the dialog feed back is: Sorry, could not detect any remote java application.